# How to set a specific range for different characters inside in a bracket that inside in a capture and group regex

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to give a regex for emails. Here is some examples:
`2020-08-22  marie_curie@hotmail.com`
`2018-10-22  ab234c_d@gmail.com`
The username part consist at least 1 character(alphabetic chars) but not more than 15, cannot have more than 3digits or special characters(-,_,&).
These characters can be in any order
I tried several regex for the username part but I couldn't control the digits and special characters. Here is my regex: 
`(19\d\d|20\d\d)-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-([0-2][0-9]|30)\s+([a-z 0-9 _-&]){1,15}@(hotmail|gmail|outlook).com`

How can I give a special range to them?

Some username examples:

`marie_curi` 
`ab567cd` 
`kd89as_` 
`abcd`

Comment: `([a-z 0-9 _-&.){1,15}` is rather a malformed regex. You have a corrupt character class here. What is your regex flavor/library?

Comment: I'm new to regex so I don't know the answer of your question but my actual regex is longer. I cut a piece from it for this specific strings. I'm actually trying to match emails and username must be like this strings. For example: 2020-08-22  marie_curie@hotmail.com (19\d\d|20\d\d)-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-([0-2][0-9]|30)\s+([a-z 0-9 _ -]){1,15}@(hotmail|gmail|outlook).com

Comment: Then please post the *actual* regex and sample strings it should match with expected result. Please update the question.

Comment: Okey sorry I'm updateing now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
^(?:19|20)\d\d-(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\s+(?!(?:[^@]*[0-9_&-]){3})[a-z0-9_&-]{1,15}@(?:hotmail|gmail|outlook)\.com$
```

Details:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?:19|20)\d\d-(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` - a datetime like string, year comes first (`19xx` and `20xx` only), then a hyphen, then a month (`1` or `01` up to `12`), `-`, and then `01` / `1` to `31`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?!(?:[^@]*[0-9_&-]){4})[a-z0-9_&-]{1,15}` - 1 to 15 alphanumeric and `_`, `&` or `-` chars with no more than three digits, `_`, `&` or `-` are allowed (3 are allowed)
- `@` - a `@` char
- `(?:hotmail|gmail|outlook)` - one of the three values, `hotmail`, `gmail`, or `outlook`
- `\.com` - `.com` string
- `$` - end of string.